# Array method filter not deleting items React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a simple todo list App where I want to manage all the state in Redux instead of React.A user can Add or Delete an item on Button Click, I am managing all the state in Redux including Onchange but I'm having an issue whenever a user deletes an item, it seems to update the DOM but whenever I try to add another item, it readds all the items that I had previously deleted.

here's a code snippet for that:

**REACT SIDE**

```
  onDeleteClick = (id) => {
    this.props.deleteItem(id);
  };
```

**REDUX ACTION**

```
export const deleteItem = (id) => {
  return {
    type: "DELETE_ITEM",
    payload: id,
  };
};
```

**REDUX REDUCER**

```
   case "DELETE_ITEM":
      const filteredState = state.todo.filter(
        (item) => item.id !== action.payload
      );
      return {
        ...state,
        todo: filteredState,
      };
```

Comment: Create a copy of the `state.todo` instead of mutating it - `[...state.todo].filter(...)`

Comment: I have done that but still doesnot seem to work

Comment: What does your `ADD_ITEM` look like? Did you change it everywhere?

Comment: add the state to the post as well please

Comment: @goto1 Here's a link to all the code (https://gist.github.com/KelvinMitaki/8e481625cc5ba66553d9ab1cbda3666f)

Comment: Your `ADD_ITEM` is incorrect - `return { ...state, todo: action.payload, text: "" };` Aren't you supposed to appending a new item to the `state.todo` array?

Comment: I found out that the problem was in the actions, I was passing the array that already had the items to the reducer hence causing it to behave that way. All I did was pass the items to the reducer via payload(Instead of the array) then transfered all the addItem action logic to the reducer,so that when I would filter the reducer would know